# ui.router doesn't working with google plus sign in directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

I'm using ui.router for routing and [google plus sign in directive](https://github.com/sirkitree/angular-directive.g-signin).

This is my `app.js`

```
  angular
  .module('app', [
    'ngAria',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngMessages',
    'ngResource',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngTouch',
    //'directive.g+signin'
  ]);
```

This is my loginController

```
angular.module('app',['directive.g+signin'])
.controller('LoginController', function ($scope) {
        $scope.$on('event:google-plus-signin-success', function (event, authResult) {
          // User successfully authorized the G+ App!
          console.log(authResult);
          console.log('Signed in!');
        });
        $scope.$on('event:google-plus-signin-failure', function (event, authResult) {
          // User has not authorized the G+ App!
          console.log('Not signed into Google Plus.');
        });
});
```

Google plus sign in button is working properly when the `directive.g+signin` put into the `LoginController`.Then doesn't load any templates from `ui.router`.

If I add `directive.g+signin` into the `app.js` and remove from the `LoginController` then my templates working fine but not google plus sign in button.

Does anybody have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing this

```
angular.module('app',['directive.g+signin'])
```

before registering your loginController overrides 'app' module that you've created in app.js. So you have 'app' module without any other external modules (except g+ directive). That's why your routing doesn't work (another thing is I don't see including ui.router module in app.js - maybe you create 'app' module even more than twice?)

To fetch existing module use angular.module('module_name') without second parameter. Make sure that angular.module with two parameters is called only once for one module name ('app' in your case).

Comment: added ui.router and directive.g+signin into the app.js. Now it's working